# Sorting Data, Getting Rid of Rows

Tags: matrix

Hi I'm trying to sort data by creating a new matrix from my current matrix data, that leaves out rows when a condition are met. For example, if I only want to keep the rows that have column 17's value as < 2, then I wrote:

```
B=[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
count=0
for n = 1:19709
    if abs(G(n,17)) < 2
        B(n,:)=G(n,:)
    end
    count=count+1

    if count>19709
        break
    end

end
```

But this code instead returns a row of zeros when the conditions are not met, rather than just leaving out the row, but I'm not sure whats wrong with the code. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is here B(n,:)=G(n,:).  You have to keep tack of how many rows you are skipping.  Should be something like B(n-k,:)=G(n,:)

Comment: @Colin That's what `count` is for. @SmcWill It should probably be `B(count,:) = G(n,:)` and `count` should be initialized to `1` (or possibly `2` if you don't want to overwrite your initial value in `B`).

Comment: Oh okay, that works, but can you explain why, because it seems to me like the for loop itself is a counter that goes through n=1:n numbers. Is it because when we skip lines then, MatLab automatically fills those lines with zeros?

Comment: Yes. Try this: `clear w; w(7,4) = 12; disp(w);` MATLAB automatically fills unspecified and previously unallocated elements with `0`.

Comment: @SmcWill if so you should have count in the if statement.